# Post a list of objects with the current user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Took me a while get it done, how to post a list/array full of JSON objects with the current user, a lot of mixed answers but this one works for me, I hope this helps someone, keep learning, keep having fun.

Next step is to set up the get_queryset to get orders per user

Comment: Thanks for posting this to help others - do you mind writing this as an answer to the question? This helps other know the question has been answered. Here's some information from the help center about how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: One small note: don't compare types directly, using `isinstance` instead is almost always better (`if isinstance(items, list): ...`), because you allow at least user-defined subclasses. Also I'd suggest checking for `if data.get('id') not in {'', None}` to avoid double dictionary lookup (and set for really minor performance improvement, you won't notice that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post a list of objects to the same order in the order table (check fk_order
variable in OrderProductsSerializer).

There are two many to many tables, OrderModel y ProductModel, so to add more fields I create the OrderProductsModel table and yeah, thats how I approached the situation, lookin for to know if this is bad or good to learn from more experienced professionals and grow , thank you people, cheers

Open to suggestions to improve and avoid share errors or bad practices, I will be editing answer.

```
############################# models.py######################################

class OrderProductsModel(models.Model):
        quantity_order_product = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        price_order_product = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True, blank=True)
        fk_product = models.ForeignKey(ProductModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        fk_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        ...
        ...
        ... more fields

############################# views.py######################################

class PostOrderProduct(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        generics.GenericAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = OrderProductsSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderProductsModel.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        items = request.data
        if isinstance(items, list):
            serializer = self.serializer_class( instance='',
                                                data=items, 
                                                many=True, 
                                                context = {
                                                            "request": self.request,
                                                            }
                                                            )
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        elif isinstance(items, dict):
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
   

############################# serializers.py ######################################
class OrderProductsListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Perform creations and updates.
        ret = []
        for data in validated_data:
            if data.get('id') not in {'', None}:
                OrderProductsModel.objects.filter(id=data['id']).update(**data)
                ret.append(data)
            else:
                ret.append(OrderProductsModel.objects.create(**data))
        return ret


class OrderProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    fk_order = serializers.HiddenField(default=OrderModel.objects.create())
    
    class Meta:
        model = OrderProductsModel
        list_serializer_class = OrderProductsListSerializer
        fields = ['fk_user', 'quantity_order_product', 'price_order_product', 'fk_product']
```

Comment: There are two many to many tables, OrderModel y ProductModel, so to add more fields I create the OrderProductsModel table and yeah, thats how I approached the situation, lookin for to know if this is bad or good to learn from more experienced professionals and grow , thank you people, cheers.